# How to add a few columns to a table in SQL?

Tags: android, sql

I want to add a few columns to my Table. I use this statement to do that in Android Studio:

```
ALTER TABLE download 
ADD vibration_on_completed INTEGER default 1,
vibration_on_failed INTEGER default 1,
message_on_completed INTEGER default 1,
message_on_failed INTEGER default 1;
```

But when I run my app I get this error:

> exception : android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax
>   error (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE download ADD
>   vibration_on_completed INTEGER default 1,vibration_on_failed INTEGER
>   default 1,message_on_completed INTEGER default 1,message_on_failed
>   INTEGER default 1;, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)

What is the problem?

Comment: Add them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Use repeated calls to `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE download 
ADD vibration_on_completed INTEGER default 1;
ALTER TABLE download 
 ADD vibration_on_failed INTEGER default 1;
ALTER TABLE download 
ADD message_on_completed INTEGER default 1;
ALTER TABLE download 
ADD message_on_failed INTEGER default 1;
```